# Acumatica-Copying data from custom field on the Sales order discount detail tab to custom field on the Invoice discount detail tab

Tags: customization, acumatica

I added custom field called `CustomField` in `SOOrderDiscountDetail` and `ARInvoiceDiscountDetail` DACs.

```
public class SOOrderDiscountDetailExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderDiscountDetail>
{
    [PXDBString(40)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="CustomField")]
    public virtual string UsrCustomField { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrCustomField : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrCustomField> { }
}

public class ARInvoiceDiscountDetailExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.AR.ARInvoiceDiscountDetail>
{
    [PXDBString(40)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="CustomField")]
    public virtual string UsrCustomField { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrCustomField : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrCustomField> { }
}
```

And I try to override the `InvoiceOrder` method in `SOInvoiceEntry`.
Am I overriding the right method and how can I override the original method?

Comment: I believe the correct approach is to first copy this new field to the Shipment. Then from the Shipment copy to the Invoice.

Comment: But as far as I check,there is no discount detail tab on shipment screen.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look whether the InvoiceCreated method is suitable for your case.

An example to override would be the following

```
 public delegate void InvoiceCreatedDelegate(ARInvoice invoice, SOOrder source);

        [PXOverride]
        public void InvoiceCreated(ARInvoice invoice, SOOrder source, InvoiceCreatedDelegate baseMethod)
        {
            baseMethod(invoice, source);

            if (invoice != null && source != null)
            {
                ARInvoiceExt invoiceExt = invoice.GetExtension<ARInvoiceExt>();
                SOOrderExt orderExt = source.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>();

                //your code here ... 
                
            }
        }
        #endregion
```